# How to catch assertion failures in MinGW gcc?

Tags: c, mingw, assert, mingw-w64

On Unix systems, I can use fork() to spawn a process, and check the flags for that thread to tell whether it aborted or not, usually through an assertion failure. Here is example code, that given a function, checks that the function call aborts.

```
bool test_assert_fail(void (*run)(void *aux), void *aux) {
    if (fork()) { // parent process
        int *status = malloc(sizeof(*status));
        assert(status != NULL);
        wait(status);
        // Check whether child process aborted
        bool aborted = WIFSIGNALED(*status) && WTERMSIG(*status) == SIGABRT;
        free(status);
        return aborted;
    }
    else { // child process
        freopen("/dev/null", "w", stderr); // suppress assertion message
        run(aux);
        exit(0); // should not be reached
    }
}
```

What's the easiest way to do something similar on Windows with the MinGW gcc compiler? Threads don't work, because a child thread aborting causes the parent thread to abort as well. I don't know how to use processes for this, because it is a function invocation.

Comment: Is it not possible to fix the code so it doesn't abort?

Comment: No, this is for testing purposes - it's expected that the code should abort. The use case is along the lines of a list struct, and checking that accessing an index out of bounds fails. I guess I could return NULL from some cases and check for that? But I'm not really a fan of that, since it obfuscates what's actually wrong.

Comment: I see. Unless you use cygwin, where you can use fork() as well, I don't see a way that would work similar.

Comment: I ended up doing an unsafe workaround that avoids spinning up a new process entirely, but is definitely wrong for anything more complex than my use case.

Answer (score 0):

NB: The functions that are being called with this are very simple and single-threaded so this is *somewhat* safer than it normally would be.

I ended up using `signal` to trap the SIGABRT and `longjmp` to resume execution:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
bool SIGABRT_RAISED = false;
jmp_buf env;

void signal_handler(int signum) {
    if (signum == SIGABRT) {
        SIGABRT_RAISED = true;
        // Reregister default, and jump out to avoid return
        signal(signum, SIG_DFL);
        longjmp(env, 1);
    }
} 
#endif

bool test_assert_fail(void (*run)(void *aux), void *aux) {
    // Windows can't use POSIX apis
    #ifndef _WIN32
    if (fork()) { // parent process
        int *status = malloc(sizeof(*status));
        assert(status != NULL);
        wait(status);
        // Check whether child process aborted
        bool aborted = WIFSIGNALED(*status) && WTERMSIG(*status) == SIGABRT;
        free(status);
        return aborted;
    }
    else { // child process
        freopen("/dev/null", "w", stderr); // suppress assertion message
        run(aux);
        exit(0); // should not be reached
    }
    #else

    signal(SIGABRT, signal_handler);
    SIGABRT_RAISED = false;
    int cstderr = _dup(_fileno(stderr));

    // Run expected failure, jumping back when SIGABRT is raised
    if (setjmp(env) == 0) {
        // suppress assertion message
        freopen("NUL", "w", stderr);
        run(aux);
    }

    // Undo suppression, since we are in the same process
    _dup2(cstderr, _fileno(stderr));
    return SIGABRT_RAISED;
    #endif
}
```